# Как удалить строку и столбец по индексу в матрице?

Tags: python, list, матрицы, список

Нужно удалить весь столбец/строку по индексу из матрицы (искал минимальный элемент главной диагонали). Теперь нужно удалить всю строку и столбец по индексу (индексом назвал `minindex`).

Искал в интернете как делать что-то подобное, но везде через `numpy`.

Должно получиться как-то так:

```
in:
[7, 9, 5]
[0, 6, 1]
[9, 6, 1]
out:
[7, 9]
[0, 6]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Решение с испольованием [list.pop](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/datastructures.html#list.pop), для того чтобы удалять элементы "на месте" (`in place`), т.е. не создавая копии матрицы / строк / столбцов:

```
idx_row, idx_col = 2, 2

# удаляем строку
_ = matrix.pop(idx_row)

# удаляем столбец
rows = len(matrix)
for i in range(rows):
    _ = matrix[i].pop(idx_col)
```

результат:

```
print(matrix)
>>> [[7, 9], [0, 6]]
```

Answer (score 3):

ну во-первых задача решается легко в лоб:

```
matrix = [
    [7, 9, 5],
    [0, 6, 1],
    [9, 6, 1],
]

i = 1
j = 2

res = []

for row in enumerate(matrix):
    if row[0] != i:
        new_row = []
        for col in enumerate(row[1]):
            if col[0] != j:
                new_row.append(col[1])
        res.append(new_row)

print(res)
```

а во-вторых приведённый выше алгоритм можно схлопнуть в одну строку, если желаете:

```
res = [[col[1] for col in enumerate(row[1]) if col[0] != j] for row in enumerate(matrix) if row[0] != i]
```

Comment: спасибо, просто я захотел удалить из матрицы не создавая новую (с ```remove```,```pop``` выходило вообще странно. Просто мой препод всегда за каждое действие делает вычеты (типо:" вы создали тут новый список, а если вам на работе скажут сделать такое-же задание, кто будет платить за память где сохраняется этот ваш новый список"). Но спасибо, я если чтоб буду спорить до конца с ним :D

Comment: а препода можно спросить делать `remove` внутри списка сколько займет времени по сравнению со сборкой нового списка :) и кстати раз уж стали опускаться на такой глубокий уровень, то еще надо разобраться, а не создаётся ли что-то внутри того же `remove` и кстати в windows система оперативную память не очень то любит сразу освобождать, поэтому все эти экономии байт - это экономии на спичках, даже если матрица 1000x1000, то проще лишние 4 мегабайта выделить на современных компах, чем мучаться с двухсвязными списками (которые кстати тоже памяти в 3 раза больше жрут, чем обычный массив - и это мин)

Comment: вот ему в понедельник об этом скажу (надеюсь не отхвачу)

Comment: и если в приведённом мной выше примере надо немного времени и памяти сэкономить, то стоит отказаться от `enumerate` и простись просто по индексам, и обращаться уже `matrix[i][j]`, а можно отказаться от `for` и `range` тогда и перейти к `while`, что еще слегка ускорит (возможно) код и лишних объектов создавать не будет

Comment: Кстати в коде выше мне выводит из матрицы ```[3, 7, 0]
[6, 8, 1]
[2, 1, 3]``` повторяющиеся строки ```[[8, 1], [8, 1], [1, 3], [1, 3]]```

Comment: понял ошибку, извините за беспокойство